# auto creating xml elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to automate the elements based on input file expression.

My input file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
    <mapping inputContext="InputRoot" outputContext="outputRoot">
        <input>InputParent/InputChild/InputSubChild</input>
        <output>OutputParent/OPChild</output>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Based on above XML I had created the below XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns="http://www.testmapping.org/mapping">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="outputCtxt" select="mappings/mapping/output"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="contextGenerator">
            <xsl:with-param name="contextPath" select="$outputCtxt"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="contextGenerator">
        <xsl:param name="contextPath" as="xs:string?"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentContext" select="substring-before($contextPath,'/')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="subContext" select="substring-after($contextPath,'/')"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$currentContext}">
            <xsl:call-template name="contextGenerator">
                <xsl:with-param name="contextPath" select="$subContext"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting the output with below format

```
<outputRoot>
   <OutputParent>
      <OPChild></OPChild>
   </OutputParent>
</outputRoot>
```

when I am trying to transform based on the input i am ending up with Expected QName error. Can I have the suggestions to address this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contextGenerator` template is not properly splitting and recursing. (There is no `/` in the argument to `contextGenerator` on the second call, so the splits fail.)

Adding the following to the template helps show the problem:

```
<xsl:message>
    [<xsl:value-of select="$currentContext"/>] 
    [<xsl:value-of select="$subContext"/>]
</xsl:message>
```

Output:

```
[OutputParent] 
[OPChild]
[] 
[]
```

The following replacement template produces the correct output:

```
<xsl:template name="contextGenerator">
    <xsl:param name="contextPath" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($contextPath, '/')">
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before($contextPath, '/')}">
                <xsl:variable name="subContext" 
                              select="substring-after($contextPath, '/')"/>
                <xsl:if test="$subContext">
                    <xsl:call-template name="contextGenerator">
                        <xsl:with-param name="contextPath" select="$subContext"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{$contextPath}"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<OutputParent>
   <OPChild/>
</OutputParent>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. @OP, your recursive template has no termination condition, so if you hadn't gotten an error, you would have had an infinite recursion (well actually a stack overflow...)

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 2.0 allows for a shorter, easier and more efficient solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOutNames" select=
  "tokenize(/*/*/output, '/')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:gen($vOutNames)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:gen" as="element()?">
  <xsl:param name="pNames" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pNames[1]">
   <xsl:element name="{$pNames[1]}">
    <xsl:sequence select="my:gen($pNames[position() >1])"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<mappings>
    <mapping inputContext="InputRoot" outputContext="outputRoot">
        <input>InputParent/InputChild/InputSubChild</input>
        <output>OutputParent/OPChild</output>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<OutputParent>
   <OPChild/>
</OutputParent>
```

Comment: If <mappings>
    <mapping inputContext="InputRoot" outputContext="outputRoot">
        <input>InputParent/InputChild/InputSubChild</input>
        <output>OutputParent/OPChild</output>
    </mapping>
</mappings>

Comment: @LaxmikanthSamudrala: Sorry, what are you trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake on other XSLT problem I was working on; but I had resolved that.

Answer (score 0):

In XML, element names have to conform to the lexical structure of [QNames](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames). You are trying to create an element called `InputParent/InputChild/InputSubChild`. This contains characters (`/`) that are not allowed in QNames.

To fix the error, you could substitute `_` for `/`... depending on what your requirements are.

E.g.

```
    <xsl:element name="{replace($currentContext, '/', '_')}">
```

Comment: I am using substring-before($contextPath,'/'); which will pull the first occurrence without / part of the result

Comment: The expected output does not contain slashes.

Comment: @lwburk: quite right. I had read the XSLT too fast. I wondered why you hadn't already posted this answer, since you'd been working on the question a while before I got here. Now I know!