# Create XML out of xpath string

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am doing a Schematron validation on an XML file and my result looks like this:

```xsl
<fired-rule context="Message[@Name='SPY_IN']"/>
<failed-assert test="@OppositeMacAddress='0x00'" location="/Module[1]/Router[1]/Message[1]">
  <text>!Error! Erwarteter Wert:"0x00"</text>
</failed-assert>

<fired-rule context="Configuration[@Address='W_ST_PLAMA_MOD_OWM_OPP']"/>
<failed-assert test="@Name='8'"
  location="/Module[1]/DriverConfigurations[1]/DriverConfiguration[20]/Configuration[10]">
  <text>!Error! Erwarteter Wert:"8"</text>
</failed-assert>
```

Now i am trying to generate a XML file that referes to the "location"-attribute.
It should look like this:

```xml
<Module>
  <Router>
    <Message>
    </Message>
  </Router>
</Module>
<Module>
  <DriverConfigurations>
    <DriverConfiguration>
      <Configuration>
      </Configuration>
    </DriverConfiguration>
  </DriverConfigurations>
</Module>
```

I tried to refer to this: [auto creating xml elements using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450381/auto-creating-xml-elements-using-xslt)
But it somehow doesnt work for me. So i have no idea how my xsl file should look like.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you post your current XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//failed-assert/@location" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@location">
    <xsl:param name="path" select="." />

    <xsl:variable name="currentContext" 
                  select="substring-before(substring-after($path,'/'), '[')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="subContext" select="substring-after($path, ']')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$currentContext}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[string($subContext)]">
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$subContext"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<root>
  <fired-rule context="Message[@Name='SPY_IN']"/>
  <failed-assert test="@OppositeMacAddress='0x00'" location="/Module[1]/Router[1]/Message[1]">
    <text>!Error! Erwarteter Wert:"0x00"</text>
  </failed-assert>

  <fired-rule context="Configuration[@Address='W_ST_PLAMA_MOD_OWM_OPP']"/>
  <failed-assert test="@Name='8'"
    location="/Module[1]/DriverConfigurations[1]/DriverConfiguration[20]/Configuration[10]">
    <text>!Error! Erwarteter Wert:"8"</text>
  </failed-assert>
</root>
```

The result is:

```
<root>
  <Module>
    <Router>
      <Message />
    </Router>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <DriverConfigurations>
      <DriverConfiguration>
        <Configuration />
      </DriverConfiguration>
    </DriverConfigurations>
  </Module>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It works great. Just one more question: why do i have to use the two <xsl:template match="/"> and  <xsl:template match="@location"> tags? Would it be possible to pack them in one  <xsl:template> tag?

Comment: No, I don't see any sensible way these could be combined into a single `template`, and it wouldn't make sense to do so. The first template is needed to pass processing on to all the `location` attributes, and the second actually handles them. If you actually have a more involved XSLT that you want to integrate the above into, then the first template may not be needed. If that's the case, perhaps you can open up a new question about how to combine this functionality into your existing XSLT.

Comment: Okay thanks! No actually i just wanted to understand what the code is doing.